# Variably assign value to particular subset of a variable in a loop in R

Tags: r, string, loops, assign

Trying again, here is a clearer account.

Thanks for your reply, but I cannot make these solutions work for me; I've probably confused the matter with my example. I'll be more specific.

Here is the data which I need to adjust before populating my new subset

```
> clientdata$Burn1
 [1] 4 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 4 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 2 2 2 1 4 2 4 2 3 3 3 4 2 4 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 4 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3
> clientdata$Burn2
 [1] 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 2 2 2 2 4 3 2 4 2 3 3 3 4 3 3 2 2 4 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
> clientdata$Forw2
 [1] 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 4 2 3 2 2 2 4 4 4 2 4 3 3 4 3 4 3 2 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 4 3 4 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3
> clientdata$Harm1
 [1] 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 4 2 3 4 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 4 3 3 2 4 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 3 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2
> clientdata$Innov1
 [1] 3 3 3 3 4 4 3 2 3 4 4 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 3 4 2 3 2 3 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 1 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 1 4 3 3 4 3 2 3 3 2 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 2 3 1 4 3 3 4 2
```

Here is my vector of variable names:

```
> rev.items.new
[1] "clientdata$Harm1_r"  "clientdata$Innov1_r" "clientdata$Burn1_r"  "clientdata$Forw2_r"  "clientdata$Burn2_r"
```

now I want to be able to do this, but in a way that isn't hard coded for those specific subsets (they might change for the next client); basically populate objects names by my list, with the value of the existing data subset subtracted from 5.

```
clientdata$Burn1_r   <- 5 - clientdata$Burn1.
clientdata$Burn2_r   <- 5 - clientdata$Burn2
clientdata$Forw2_r   <- 5 - clientdata$Forw2
clientdata$Harm1_r   <- 5 - clientdata$Harm1
clientdata$Innov1_r   <- 5 - clientdata$Innov1
```

The output should then be

```
> clientdata$Burn1_r
[1] -1 -2 -2 -2 -3 -3 -3 ...
> clientdata$Burn2_r
[1] -3 -2 -2 -3 -3 -3 -3 ...
> clientdata$Forw2_r
[1] -2 -2 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 ...
> clientdata$Harm1_r
[1] -3 -3 -3 -3 -2 -3 -3 ...
> clientdata$Innov1_r
[1] -2 -2 -2 -2 -1 -1 -2 ...
```

Is that clearer? So sorry for being ambiguous, not great at asking for help.

Comment: Could you show some example dataset and your expected output

Comment: There have been so many questions lately with people using `assign()`. I don't get it. But in R, you should try to avoid it. It almost always makes more sense to collect related values in a list or vector rather than assigning them to a bunch of different variables in your current environment.

Comment: When items are in a list, you can use `data[[paste0(as.character(names[i]),"_new")]]` to get at values in a list with a string.

Comment: I have searched, trust me, I'm not great at searching Google for "r" yet, there must be a trick I'm missing. 

Why doesn't assign() work for the format "data$name", but does for "name"?

Also, MrFlick, while I appreciate that I'm new here and duplicates are annoying for mods, your comment did not link to any relevant threads. Would you mind updating it, if not for the noobs like myself who find this from a Google search but struggle to find the others.

EDIT* just caught your update, thanks for the code, I'll do more research to get this done. My apologies for the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done easily without `assign`, but if this is for understanding the `assign` mechanism

```
curr.object <- paste(colnames(data), 'new', sep="_")
for(i in seq_along(curr.object)){
 assign('data', `[[<-`(data, curr.object[i], value=5-data[,i]))
 }
data
#   foo bar doo foo_new bar_new doo_new
#1   9  20   7      -4     -15      -2
#2  14  13   8      -9      -8      -3
#3   3   7  20       2      -2     -15
#4  18   2  12     -13       3      -7
#5   3   6  14       2      -1      -9
```

#### Update

The following is a bit more complex/indirect/unusual etc. way of creating variable in the dataset. ie. first create  new variables in the global environment and then assign it back to the dataset.

```
rev.items.new <- paste(colnames(clientdata), 'r', sep="_")
rev.items.new
#[1] "Burn1_r"  "Burn2_r"  "Harm1_r"  "Innov1_r"
for(i in seq_along(rev.items.new)){
 assign(rev.items.new[i], 5-clientdata[,i])
}

head(Burn1_r)
#[1] 1 2 2 2 3 3

clientdata[rev.items.new] <- mget(rev.items.new)
head(clientdata)
#    Burn1 Burn2 Harm1 Innov1 Burn1_r Burn2_r Harm1_r Innov1_r
#1     4     2     2      3       1       3       3        2
#2     3     3     2      3       2       2       3        2
#3     3     3     2      3       2       2       3        2
#4     3     2     2      3       2       3       3        2
#5     2     2     3      4       3       3       2        1
#6     2     2     2      4       3       3       3        1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 5*3, replace=TRUE), ncol=3,
    dimnames=list(NULL, c('foo', 'bar', 'doo'))) )

clientdata <-  structure(list(Burn1 = c(4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3), Burn2 = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3
), Forw2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3), Harm1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2), Innov1 = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 
3, 4, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -67L), .Names = c("Burn1", "Burn2", 
"Forw2", "Harm1", "Innov1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Alex As I mentioned earlier, you should provide some example data and expected result.  Based on the code showed, it seemed that you were looking for this.  Also, it is not a good idea to use `$`, instead use `[`, ie, what I did

Comment: Edited my original, thanks again its friday arvo and I'm really bothered.

Comment: @Alex I can't find any edit in your original

Comment: Redone sorry, majorly stressed and making mistakes. Please see edites now

Comment: @Alex If I understand your new example, it is done in the same way here only replacing the names

Comment: The idea is the output should be 5 separate vectors of values (named after my vector of strings) that are the value of their matching values in the original data file (i.e. sans "_r").
Trouble is assigning an objects name in a loop while populating its value with that from another variable object name.

Comment: @Alex If it is vector of values, why should it be `clientdata$Burn1_r` instead of just `Burn1_r`.  You are assigning it to the dataframe  object `clientdata` as `Burn1_r` column

Comment: correct, I'm making that vector of values, then adding it back to the original dataset

Comment: @Alex My method simply adds that to the original dataset as new columns.  I don't really understand this roundabout way.

Comment: so colnames(data) in your example, does that call ALL colnames from data? My client.data file has many many more columns that I'm not operating on here. Also, what is this `[[<-` ?

Comment: @Alex One option is to create the vectors as `Burn1_r`, `Harm1` etc and then assign using  `clientdata[, rev.items.new] <- ...`

Comment: @Alex Yes colnames(data) calls all the columns even if it is 100000 columns.  `[[<-` we are assigning the new variables to the dataset.

Comment: that makes a bit more sense, i tried that but it strugles with factors maybe? 

`> clientdata[,rev.items.new] <- 5- clientdata[,rev.items]
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: @Alex I updated it above.   Your `rev.items` is not clear.  It should be `5-clientdata` if all the columns are used and are in the same order as in the rev.items.new.  Also, check the `str(clientdata)` to see if the columns are numeric or factor

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your assistance. i'm clearly new to this and finding the transition from MATLAB to be bumpy. I've not solved it in my head, but will use all of your valued responses to learn where i went wrong. Enjoy your weekend, and thanks again.

Comment: @Alex Glad to help you.  Enjoy your weekend as well.

Comment: Not sure you're still there, I've gotten a bit further. The below line works

`assign(curr.obj, 5- clientdata[,rev.items[i]])

> clientdata$Burn2_r
 [1] 2 2 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 1 2 `

But not in this loop

`for(i in seq_along(rev.items.new)){
  curr.obj <- paste0("clientdata$",as.character(rev.items.new[i]))
  assign(curr.obj, 5- clientdata[,rev.items[i]])
}

>Warning message:
In Ops.factor(5, clientdata[, rev.items[i]]) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`

Why is that?

Comment: @Alex As I mentioned earlier, please do avoid using `$`.